# Solution for tracking state changes of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

`UIButton` provides many state-dependent settings (image, titleColor, etc.).
I have manually added a subview to a button which shall react to the buttons state changes.
How would I do that? Should I try to map `UIControlEvent`s on state changes?

Answer (score 6):

You could do it by adding KVO observers for the button's selected and highlighted properties, but that's a lot more complicated than creating a subclass of `UIButton` and overloading the `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` methods. You'd do that like this:

```
//MyCustomButton.h

@interface MyCustomButton : UIButton

@end


//MyCustomButton.m

@implementation MyCustomButton

- (void)setUp
{
    //add my subviews here
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //this is called when you create your button in code
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    //this is called when you create your button in interface builder
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    super.selected = selected;
    //update my subviews here
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    super.highlighted = highlighted;
    //update my subviews here
}

@end
```

You can then create your custom buttons in code, or them in interface builder by dragging a regular `UIButton` onto your view and then settings its class to `MyCustomButton` in the inspector.